# How to append a delimiter after Carriage return

Tags: unix, carriage-return, linefeed

I have a record as below

1, "All of the following:

Electronic**LF**
Fax machine**LF**
Hard Copy**LF**
In Person**LF**
Mail Delivery**LF**
Telephone",No,Immediate**CR**LF**

I have to replace LineFeed (LF) in above record with space except when at the record end (as soon as when i find Carriage Return).

Please guide me to do it in unix.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline , LineFeed in Unix or Unix-Like system is `\n`. Just to search `\n` and replace with space.

Comment: It's replacing at the end of the record also, I should not replace LineFeed after CR